# Something relative to prediction

Tags: python

Sample datasets

```
id    ,  code ,  ref_range,  value , finding , type
1     ,  AK   ,  2 -  9   ,   5    , normal  , 1
2     ,  AK   ,  2 -  9   ,   1    , low     , 1
3     ,  AK   ,  2 -  9   ,   10   , high    , 1
4     ,  NN   ,  < 5      ,   9    , high    , 2
5     ,  MM   ,  > 5      ,   9    , normal  , 3
```

problem:
is there a way in PYTHON to auto predict the value , finding & type base on input below.

sample input

```
input  code = XX, ref_range = < 4 , value = 5.5 
expected output finding = high , type = 2    

input  code = XX, ref_range = < 4 , value = 3
expected output finding = normal , type = 2

input  code = X1, ref_range = 1 - 4 , value = 0.7
expected output finding = low , type = 1
```

I know you guys will tell me I can use switch & If statement but given the scenario that values & reference range are arbitrary. I am not asking for code I am asking for an Idea or library that can help to solve this in artificial or predictive manner.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your example: It looks like you define type based on ref_range, and finding based on if the value is within the specified range.

To me: It looks like you have three options. 
1. If you can, split ref_range into two parts high_limit and low_limit: 
That would let you run a simple if/elif/else statement to generate both the type and the finding.

2. Parse the ref_range string so that you have a high_limit and low_limit, and then use the if/elif/else statements. 
   That would be simple enough to do, I would use something like the following code to split the ref_string:

```
import re
values = re.split('-|<|>',a)
if '-' in ref_string:
    type = 1
    high_limit = values[1]
    low_limit = values[0]
elif '<' in ref_string:
    type = 2
    high_limit = None
    low_limit = values[0]
elif '>' in ref_string:
    type = 3
    high_limit = None
    low_limit = values[0]
else:
    raise ValueError("ref_string did not contain valid delimiter")

#Then process for 'finding' based on high/low limits.
```

3. Use a package like Pandas that will let you manipulate the data as a large data-frame with a *lot* more flexibility, and much greater speed of execution.

Comment: thanks @Michael, but given the situation that ref_range is arbitrary so more likely the ref range can have >= 5, <= 5 , 1 ~ 10 
so instead of adding more if else along the operations would be better if there is some kind artificial intelligence that can detect it base on the data,

Comment: Ah, Fair enough, how big a dataset do you have to train a model with? 
It's absolutely possible to train a machine learning model to recognize and classify text structures but unless you're already familiar with a python compatible ML system e.g scikitlearn I really doubt that it would save any time.